# How to put spaces in blade template

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, laravel-blade

I'm working with https://github.com/cntaoyu/CI-Blade framework and my code is : (works fine and prints too)

```
    @foreach($tbl_data as $d) 
        @foreach($d as $c) 
            {{$c}}  //I want space after this, new line in fact
        @endforeach 
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Just add `<br>` next to `{{$c}}`, it allows HTML

Comment: Yes, it worked ! Thank you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @foreach($tbl_data as $d) 
    @foreach($d as $c) 
        {{$c}}  <br> //if it is blade
    @endforeach 
@endforeach
```